# GAE - cannot add JSP file to project

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been creating simple GAE project - all what I did before is index.html. Now, I want to add file createAccount.jsp to WAR directory. Eclipse gives me an error: "cannot compile jsp file..."

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like there's an error in your jsp file.  Does Eclipse give any reasons for the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSPs are supported on GAE: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps.html

As @Riley already noted in comment, it must be an error in JSP file. Start with a simple JSP and then start adding functionality.

**Update**

As noted in comments, this was a problem of JDK version.

Comment: Ehhh, it was problem with JDK. Eclipse had as deafult JRE...I changed it but I've got another error:

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:228)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:164)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)

Comment: at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: defaultZoneTL
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1899)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:222)
 ... 5 more

Comment: It seems to be the problem with JDK 1.7. GAE uses 1.6. Try to install JDK 1.6 and then set it in Eclipse.